Running IronPdf in Linux docker container crashes
Here's a simple .NET console app that I've containerized that uses IronPdf. The packages I've installed are IronPdf.Linux (2024.11.4) and IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Linux (2024.11.6).
using IronPdf;

IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingMode = IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingModes.All;
Installation.ChromeGpuMode = IronPdf.Engines.Chrome.ChromeGpuModes.Disabled;
Installation.LinuxAndDockerDependenciesAutoConfig = true;

try
{
    ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

Here's the dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build

WORKDIR /source

COPY . .

RUN dotnet restore $(find . -name "*.csproj") --use-current-runtime

RUN dotnet publish --configuration Debug --no-restore pdf.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /source/bin/Debug/net8.0/publish/ .

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    chromium \
    fonts-liberation \
    libappindicator3-1 \
    libasound2 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libnss3 \
    libxss1 \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libnspr4 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    ca-certificates \
    wget \
    --no-install-recommends
USER nobody

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "pdf.dll"]

Yet the container crashes whenever it tries to instantiate the ChromePdfRenderer. The debug logs IronPdf generates aren't too telling either. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

i want to mention that based on the logs that this command didnot execute inside the container RUN apt-get update \     && apt-get install -y
kind of strange that the user inside the container have no access to some debian systemfiles.
if these packages are essential for your program it might be the problem.
logs; `Executing command 'apt update' in '/app/runtimes/linux-x64/native'
Reading package lists...
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ ...`

To resolve the issue, we recommend enabling the SingleProcess mode when running in debugging mode. Installation.SingleProcess = true;
Additionally, please update your Dockerfile to temporarily switch to the root user before RUN apt-get update... to ensure proper permissions, and then revert to the nobody user after the installation is complete for enhanced security. These changes should help resolve the issues you're experiencing.
